Ruby on Rails 7 devise and ldap login issue
I'm using Devise and devise_ldap_authenticatable gem in my rails app. I want users to be able to log in with their username, not their email address but there is an issue. When I enter my login and password and click log in in the Chrome browser, the message "include the @ sign in the email address" appears. But when I enter the email address an error appears in the logs about the inability to authorize using the specified user, which is true because there is no such user in the domain. So it seems that LDAP integration works fine but there is some validation in the devise configuration that I can't find. Below is my current configuration
devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> LDAP Configuration
  config.ldap_logger = true
  config.ldap_create_user = true
  config.ldap_update_password = false
  config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.authentication_keys = [:username]
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:username]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:username]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12
  config.responder.error_status = :unprocessable_entity
  config.responder.redirect_status = :see_other
end

app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :ldap_authenticatable,
         :trackable, :timeoutable
  enum role: {logged_in: 0, reader: 1, regular: 2, moderator: 3, acceptor: 4, admin: 5}
end

controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    super
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    super
  end

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_in, keys: [:username])
  end
end

app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb
<h2>Log in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :username, "Enter your login" %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :username, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "username" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "users/shared/links" %>

I'm using
Rails 7.1.3.2
ruby 3.2.3
devise (4.9.4)
devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.8.7)

What is missing here?

I found the issue. It should be
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :username, "Enter your login" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "username" %>
</div>

instead
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :username, "Enter your login" %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :username, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "username" %>
</div>

The devise view generator uses default email configuration.
